# an alternative to using IN during mysql executions

Tags: mysql, sql

is there an alternative to using the **IN** clause in mysql-

i am concerned that its not efficent.

easier if i explain.

3 table:

> TABLE ONE = USER
>   TABLE TWO = list of languages
>
> TABLE THREE =
>   connection table between above two (i.e THE language that users speak)

**below is my query**

SELECT
                    u.name

```
            FROM 
                user u
            WHERE     

                    u.id IN (
                    SELECT user_id
                    FROM user_lang_join_table
                    WHERE lang_id = 4)
```

[here are my tables and query in sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e331)

my problem is that i have a table that contains millions of records.

Accordingly, using an **IN** in this context will mean that I need to repeat the above exercise for each of the records. this is obviously not efficient

**BELOW ARE MY TABLES;**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lang` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;


INSERT INTO `lang` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'english'),
(2, 'french'),
(3, 'german'),
(4, 'Italian'),
(5, 'Spanish'),
(6, 'Portuguese');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'tom'),
(2, 'cyril'),
(3, 'elain'),
(4, 'jerry'),
(5, 'susan'),
(6, 'micky');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_lang_join_table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lang_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=23 ;


INSERT INTO `user_lang_join_table` (`id`, `user_id`, `lang_id`) VALUES
(1, 4, 4),
(2, 3, 4),
(3, 2, 3),
(4, 2, 4),
(5, 3, 2),
(6, 1, 3),
(7, 4, 2),
(8, 5, 3),
(9, 4, 6),
(10, 3, 3),
(11, 2, 2),
(12, 3, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

`IN` has gotten more efficient in more recent versions of MySQL.  However, you can replace it with `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM user u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM user_lang_join_table uljt
              WHERE uljt.lang_id = 4 AND uljt.user_id = u.id
             );
```

For this query, you want an index on `user_lang_join_table(user_id, lang_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about this. MySQL will do the optimization in rewrite phase for u.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is about as efficient as this type of request can be. If you really want to avoid an in query you could use a join, but with large sets of data the in query should still prove to have better performance.

```
select distinct( name ) from user inner join user_lang_join_table on user.id = user_lang_join_table.user_id where user_lang_join_table.lang_id=4;
```

I added the distinct to prevent elain from appearing twice.

Note: This is not how a join query is typically intended to be used as you do not intend to take advantage of the joined columns other than filtering on columns in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

An approach that *might* perform better would be to use an inner join:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM user_lang_join_table j
JOIN user u ON u.id = j.user_id
WHERE j.lang_id = 4
```

Also, from the DDL in the question, it looks as though you don't currently have an index on user_id and lang_id in the join table - if not, try adding one (if possible).